# Authentication causes Azure Function to respond with status code 404

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, openid-connect

I have a 6.0 in-process Azure Function v4 on consumption tier which works just fine.
I want to add AAD B2C authentication to the function, and call the function through APIM's `validate-jwt` policy.

Whenever I configure Settings > Authentication the function goes 404. I don't think it's a cold start issue, it's not just a delay, but the app doesn't come back.

I tried setting it up both with "Microsoft" as a provider and "OpenID Connect". There is a dedicated AppRegistration for this Function under B2C tenant and I'm generating client id & secret on it, applying to this tab.

Not super sure where to look for details, but setting Authentication causes some configurations to go bad for sure.

Comment: Are you getting the 404 when running from "Test/Run" or directly triggered as a user?